# Windows 10 seems to be crashing on keypress

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bsod, crash

I've come to suspect that my Windows 10 BSODs are related to keyboard/usb.

**TL;DR**
Windows 10 has been crashing on keypress every 8-12 work hours for around 6 months now and it was stable before. No problems with hours of gaming with a gamepad. Major things changed between now and before are new GPU and installation of Docker. Can't tell if crashes started at the same time and can't afford to remove either.

---

My work involves a lot of typing and most of the time the BSOD happens exactly (audio buffer starts looping the exact moment) when I press a key on my keyboard. I've noticed this mostly in Command Prompt, Atom or while typing something in Chrome. On the other hand I can play games for hours without problems using a Xbox One gamepad.

I estimate the crashes happen roughly every 8-12 work hours. I write code, so that's a lot of keypresses.

Bug check string in these situations is always DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL and BlueScreenView shows ntoskrnl.exe to be the culprit.

During my previous employment my PC was mostly crash-free. Between that and my current employment I've upgraded my GPU. Since there was months of unemployment in between, I hadn't noticed similar crashes then. For my new job I had to install Docker but I can't even say if the crashes started at the same time. Can't really afford to test either one blindly.

Any search so far have yielded either too broad results or none at all, so I thought I'd see if anyone here has heard of anything similar.

Comment: Perhaps it's not actually a bug with your keyboard but one with say.. your USB stack, the audio driver etc. I've experienced two cases where a broken audio driver causes all kinds of strangeness with the wifi. (both laptops).
Regardless it's likely due to incompatibility between docker and some other driver.

Comment: @jdwolf Yeah, I don't suspect the keyboard per se. The crashes seem to be connected to keypresses somehow though. I know USB can be really unreliable, but since that's all I know, I have no clue how to narrow down the possibilities. I've tried changing ports a couple of times but the bsods still happen.

Comment: activate "special pool" option in DriverVerifier and [debug the dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) and not this bluescrrenview crap

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks. I'm not familiar with Driver Verifier or Windbg. I got as far as run verifier -> Custom settings -> [x] Special Pool(nothing else). Do I select unsigned drivers only or perhaps all drivers? What next?
I'd like to avoid having to post follow-up questions about unclear instructions and getting something stuck in a fan, because with my experience on this topic that might very well happen.

Comment: activate "Special Pool" for all 3rd party drivers.

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I appreciate it! I haven't encountered any BSODs since asking this, so I can't provide more information. Honestly I forgot about this whole thing but I'm sure I'll remember to come back here when I get a couple more BSODs :) It's really annoying how this is such a consistently inconsistent problem and troubleshooting like this becomes extra slow.

Answer (score -1):

Remove overclock

disabled Driver Verifier

Besides, ntoskrnl.exe BSOD issue usually related to bad memory. If you ensure that computer has installed the latest USB controller driver and Windows is up to date, you need to check your memory state via Memtest

Look at this similar case.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-3023677/bsod-caused-ntoskrnl-exe.html

Comment: Thanks. I've used stock clocks for a while now. Overnight memtest shows no errors with 32GB DDR3. Drivers should also be as recent as they can be. I think driver verifier should also be disabled, but I'll check.